# finding range between two dates in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm not experienced in haml and at the moment trying to learn as I go along. Below is my haml code. I'm trying to show a button when the date range is equal to 4 or more days. Basically the requirement is that the button is hidden when it is only 4 days until the end date..

```
  - range = booking.start_on..booking.end_on
  - if range >= 4
    = link_to "#",
      class: 'btn-flat btn-flat-split',
      title: "Extend Booking",
      data: { method: request.primary_action.method } do
      = "Extend Booking"
      %i.icon-chevron-right
```

I'm getting this error :

```
NoMethodError at /ideas/50114
undefined method `>=' for "06 Feb 2020".."20 Feb 2020":Range
```

I'm not 100% sure if the range is getting the right output or declared correctly..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is a range of days, which is a Range object that doesn't implement the `>=` method.

What you need is to get the number of days of difference between each date object, using `to_date` for that:

```
p (booking.end_on.to_date - booking.start_on.to_date).to_i # 14
```

So, for your case:

```
- if (booking.end_on.to_date - booking.start_on.to_date).to_i >= 4
  ...
```

It's a Ruby error, not Haml.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got this : ```undefined method `-' for "20 Feb 2020":String
Did you mean?  -@```

Comment: Sorry, I tried that in a pure Ruby environment, without realizing both variables are strings. See the updated answer.